# Opencart's $this->config->get('module_var_name')

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to customize an Opencart payment module, I see many places where config info is being used, but I cant find anything that creates what variables are in use. I know in the admin pages if I select 'paypal standard' I can set all the 'config' info, but I cant find the 'model' underlining it, is there a model, I wish to create a new config setting, settable inside the admin page

How does the admin page know which variables to set? If I change the admin 'view' for the payment module to show a new setting, will that setting automatically be available in the catalog?

example of some of the config data in use...

admin\view\template\payment\pp_standard.tpl (paypal admin template), allows 'test mode' to be set....

```
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry_test; ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($pp_standard_test) { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="pp_standard_test" value="1" checked="checked" />
          <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
          <input type="radio" name="pp_standard_test" value="0" />
          <?php echo $text_no; ?>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <input type="radio" name="pp_standard_test" value="1" />
          <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
          <input type="radio" name="pp_standard_test" value="0" checked="checked" />
          <?php echo $text_no; ?>
          <?php } ?></td>
      </tr>
```

catalog\controller\poayment\pp_standard.php (paypal catalog controller), uses above 'test mode' to determine which paypal Webservice URL to hit..

```
if (!$this->config->get('pp_standard_test')) {
    $curl = curl_init('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
} else {
    $curl = curl_init('https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
}
```

I was expecting to find a 'model' somewhere with 'pp_standard_test' defined somewhere, but I've found nothing, any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. There is much advice online stating that the 'paypal standard' payment module is a good place to start, but more than likely, we wont be using paypal, it's the principle I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: try with -> catalog->model->payment?

Comment: @nevermind catalog\model\payment\pp_standard.php does some 'should this payment method be available' logic, then it returns an array with keys ['code', 'title' and 'sort_order'], all of which are used on the checkout page and help populate a 'list of payment methods', nothing to do with settings on admin page.

Comment: Settings (payment and other settings) are stored to database when you activate it in admin panel - in table 'setting'... model for settings is inside model/setting folder...i hope that helps a little...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OpenCart administration a `admin/model/setting/setting.php` model is used for such a modules/extensions where only a *key group name* and the posted data is provided to be stored in the `setting` DB table... (and optionally a `store_id` in multistore installation as well)

You could check any of controllers in **`admin/controller/payment/`** dir to see how is this model used (`pp_standard.php`, from line 10 within OC 1.5.5.1):

```
$this->load->model('setting/setting');

if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
    $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('pp_standard', $this->request->post);

    $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

    $this->redirect($this->url->link('extension/payment', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
}
```

This will write all the form data into the `setting` DB table while form field's name is used as a key to the value filled within.

Thus if You call

```
$this->config->get('<KEY>');
```

You can get the value that is set for the `<KEY>` key.

Comment: Great, i've found the 'pp_standard' group in the <prefix>_setting table in mysql, and I can see everything getting stored in there. So essentially (as my php is a bit weak, all this MVC stuff doesn't help), any setting that I create on the admin page will automatically be inserted into the DB 'setting' table with <key><value>, the <key> being what I name the html input field? does it do something like 'all posted variables starting with 'pp_standard' in the name should be stored in the database? is that group set independently anywhere? and yeah, posted vars must all start with th group name?

Comment: The *group name* is just because You then can use `setting` model to get all the settings for this group. It should tie together all the settings for one module/extension. Yes, the name of the field is the `<key>` and value filled in it is the `<value>` then. And no, You do not need to name the field names starting with the group name, it is just for better recognition if You use `$this->config->get('group_property');` on frontend to be wise the property is from the concrete group of settings...

Comment: i see `$this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('pp_standard', $this->request->post);`, so ALL variables it finds in `post` will be inserted into the db with the group 'pp_standard' in this instance? Thanks for the help @shadyyx

Comment: Exactly as You understood it. If You then call `$this->model_setting_setting->getSetting('pp_standard');` You can on the other hand retrieve all the settings for this group name.

Comment: I am having a similar issue to what you are describing here. I have a setting in group um key alert_color and an setting in group um_redux key alert_color and $this->config->get('alert_color'); pulls in group um property