# Custom multilingual inputs - opencart

Tags: input, field, opencart, multilingual

What is the pattern for creating a multilingual input in opencart for admin side.
For example I want to have two `List Description Limit` inputs, one for each language.
Like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKRpH.png). So I can control from admin side the list limit for every language.
Currently I use this pattern to create a custom input, but this is not language dependent:

```html
File: admin/view/template/extension/theme/theme_default.tpl
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputId"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $help_inputName; ?>"><?php echo $label_inputName; ?></span></label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="theme_default_inputName" value="<?php echo $theme_default_inputName; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $label_inputName; ?>" id="inputId" class="form-control" />
    <?php if ($error_inputName) { ?>
    <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_inputName; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
</fieldset>

File: admin/language/en-gb/extension/theme/theme_default.php
//Language strings
$_['help_inputName']                   = 'helpTxt';
$_['label_inputName']                  = 'labelForInput';
$_['error_inputName']                  = 'errorForInput';

File: admin/controller/extension/theme/theme_default.php
//Language strings
$text_strings = array(
    'help_inputName',
    'label_inputName',
    'error_inputName'
);

foreach ($text_strings as $text) {
    $data[$text] = $this->language->get($text);
}

//Error handling
if (isset($this->error['inputName'])) {
    $data['error_inputName'] = $this->error['inputName'];
} else {
    $data['error_inputName'] = '';
}

//Custom field
if (isset($this->request->post['theme_default_inputName'])) {
    $data['theme_default_inputName'] = $this->request->post['theme_default_inputName'];
} elseif (isset($setting_info['theme_default_inputName'])) {
    $data['theme_default_inputName'] = $setting_info['theme_default_inputName'];
} else {
    $data['theme_default_inputName'] = "customText";
}

//Validation
if (!$this->request->post['theme_default_inputName']) {
    $this->error['inputName'] = $this->language->get('error_inputName');
}
```

Comment: I would imagine that it would be best to determine if there are other fields that would be affected by this sort of rule i.e. limiting input length by language, then add a new tab to the theme's settings page, that tab could have a drop down to select the language and you could then create the different config's for them based on the selection. Have I understand your question properly?

Comment: Yes I would like to create a new tab, I know how to do that, I just don't know the right way to create variables dependent of language. Yes.

Comment: Here's a question and answer on how to use custom keys in the opencart settings table. The answer shows how you would use the model to get and set the values. So you could create a key `description_length_en` and another `desctiption_length_ru` then in the controller, you get the language on the page and use a switch statement to show the right value.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938200/opencarts-this-config-getmodule-var-name